# running async code within a function which contains blocking code

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

```py
import asyncio
import time


def blocking_function():
    print("Blocking function called")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Blocking function finished")


async def concurrent_function():
    for x in range(10):
        print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    print("Main function called")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_function)
    await concurrent_function()
    print("Main function finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When attempting to run a blocking function while asyncio code is also running, this works perfectly. However, if I have a funciton which contains blocking code (eg. a libary which is not asyncronous I am unable to do this)
Because the function contains both blocking code, and asynconrous code I cannot use `run in executor`. How can I get around this?

The below code unfortunetly errors due to the `blocking_function` not being awaited, but you annot use that in conjunction with `run_in_executor`

```py
async def blocking_function():
    for x in range(4):
        print("Blocking function called")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Blocking function finished")
        print("Async code running:")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Async code finished")


async def concurrent_function():
    for x in range(10):
        print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    print("Main function called")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_function)
    await concurrent_function()
    print("Main function finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: There is [a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads) made exactly for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create an event loop in the second thread and run the async function there.

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def blocking_function():
    for x in range(4):
        print("Blocking function called")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Blocking function finished")
        print("Async code running:")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Async code finished")

def async_blocking_function_runner(func):
    # creates another event loop in the other thread and runs func in it
    res = asyncio.run(func())
    return res


async def concurrent_function():
    for x in range(10):
        print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    print("Main function called")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    res = loop.run_in_executor(None, async_blocking_function_runner, blocking_function)
    await concurrent_function()
    await res  # make sure the task in second thread is done
    print("Main function finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```